# From a certain network is not responding to connections or pings

Tags: networking, server, ping

We have an office network and a server network. Connectivity works fine apart from one machine running Ubuntu 22, all servers are on Hyper-V

This particular server is not responding to ping from the office network :

```
IP 172.18.13.20 > 172.16.45.193: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 154, length 40
  IP 172.18.13.20 > 172.16.45.193: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 155, length 40
```

Seems to be just ignoring the requests. connectivity from anywhere else is perfect

If I try to ping my office workstation  I seem to get a rejection from the office router:

```
PING 172.18.13.20 (172.18.13.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.18.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I ping my workstation from any other server on the server network it works fine.

The routing table on the problem vm is :

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.44.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

====

The question is what on earth would make the Ubuntu server seemingly ignore ping requests, when all other servers on the same network respond fine

Thanks for reading

George

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution, the server is running Docker and one of the Docker network IP ranges is identical to that of my office network.
so when I was snooping the network I specified interface eth0. The ping replies were not seen because they were being directed to the Docker private network.
so simple, but took all day to figure out :)